# how do you create sections/subsections and ggplot in knitr word document

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I have a data frame that has cpu usage for many different applications by server. Something like this:

```
data

    App   Server   Date Cpu
    Web   web01    1/1/2015 10
    Web   web01    1/2/2015 10
    Web   web01    1/3/2015 20
    Web   web01    1/4/2015 30
    Web   web01    1/5/2015 4
    TomCat   tom01    1/1/2015 10
    TomCat   tom01    1/2/2015 10
    TomCat   tom01    1/3/2015 20
    TomCat   tom01    1/4/2015 30
    TomCat   tom01    1/5/2015 4
```

I need to be able to create ggplot charts using knitr with sections. For example, first section will be Web, next will be TomCat and so forth. I need to be able to do this in loop since there are hundreds of applications.

I am trying this but I dont see the charts in the word document:

```
{r qplot,fig.width=8, fig.height=5, message=FALSE}

library(ggplot2)

app<-unique(data$App, drop=TRUE)
app<-droplevels(app)

for (app in data){ 
 ggplot(subset(data, App %in% data), aes(Date, Cpu, group=Server, colour=server))+geom_line() + facet_wrap(~Server)

}
```

I have two questions:

1. how do I create sections automatically in knitr like sweave would do?
2. How would I create ggplot charts within for loop?

I'd really appreciate any insight.

Comment: why not just facet by App and Server together? another option is to build a list of ggplot objects and plot them however you want them grouped with different grid.arrange calls.

Comment: @hrbrmstr, I need each app to be in different sectio for easy readibility, other wise, everything will be in one chart.

Comment: With hundreds of applications, I would think that a facet by `app` would make the plot run off the page. Try adding `results='asis'` to your chunk options and then put `cat("## section break")` after the `ggplot` call. You can replace section break with the value of `app`, or some other clever naming scheme.

Comment: @Benjamin, I dont see the plot in word document after I run Knit Word. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like there are a couple of things you need to change:

1. your `for` loop should start with `for(a in app){`
2. Your subset call should be `subset(data, App %in% a)`
3. Your `ggplot` needs to be wrapped in `print`
4. A couple other minor typos.  Here's the code that works for me.

---

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: word_document
---

```{r}
data <- 
"App   Server   Date Cpu
Web   web01    1/1/2015 10
Web   web01    1/2/2015 10
Web   web01    1/3/2015 20
Web   web01    1/4/2015 30
Web   web01    1/5/2015 4
TomCat   tom01    1/1/2015 10
TomCat   tom01    1/2/2015 10
TomCat   tom01    1/3/2015 20
TomCat   tom01    1/4/2015 30
TomCat   tom01    1/5/2015 4"

data <- read.table(text = data, header = TRUE)
```

## Start the Plots

```{r qplot,fig.width=8, fig.height=5, message=FALSE, results = 'asis'}

library(ggplot2)

app<-unique(data$App, drop=TRUE)
app<-droplevels(app)

for (a in app){ 
 print(ggplot(subset(data, App %in% a), 
        aes(Date, Cpu, group=Server, colour=Server)) +
    geom_line() + 
    facet_wrap(~Server))
  cat("\n\n## New Plot\n\n")
}
```
````

Comment: thank you for this. Also, is it possible to put sections with page numbers like sweave so that the document is easily readable and browsable.

Comment: If you mean like a table of contents, no.  The word format of RMarkdown doesn't support that feature.  You can see more about the supported features on page 5 of this document. https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/rmarkdown-reference.pdf

Comment: as you can see I am new to this. Is there an option to set the margin of the page etc?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of...at least not for the Word output.  I find the Word output is very limited, and I don't use it very often myself.

Comment: Do you have a good template that you can share? I need to put together a document asap.

Comment: I don't have any Word templates.  Sorry.

Comment: what about a pdf template?